# Is every function that can be analytically continued asymptotically regular?

Tags: complex-analysis, divergent-series, regularization, analytic-continuation

Consider a divergent series $S$ which can be regularized to a number of convergent ones $S^{n}_\epsilon$ which asymptote to the series $S$ when the regularizing parameter $\epsilon$ is removed.

$$ \forall n: \qquad  S^{n}_\epsilon \stackrel{\epsilon \to 0}{\longrightarrow} S \,.$$

We call the divergent series '*asymptotically regular*' if there is a finite number $\alpha \lt \infty$ such that

$$ \forall n: \qquad  S^{n}_\epsilon = \mathcal O(1/\epsilon) + \alpha +\mathcal O(\epsilon) \,, $$

and we call $\alpha$ the '*finite part of $S$*'.

I wish to learn what characterizes the asymptotic regularity of divergences, as in why some of them are asymptotically regular. In that spirit, now consider analytic continuation as a method of regularization.

By some witchcraft, we expect the following conjecture to hold true:

> A divergent series S is asymptotically regular and its finite part is $\alpha$ if and only if there is a function $f:D \subset \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ so that for some $s\notin D: f(s)= S$ in form, and it can be analytically continued to $F:\mathbb C \to \mathbb R$ such that  $F(s) = \alpha$.

I am looking for a proof or disproof of the above conjecture. Thank you.

Comment: Your question isn't well-defined. Note that $\sum_{k\ge 1}^{(Z)}(-1)^{k+1} = \lim_{s \to 0} \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k+1} k^{-s}$ (where $\sum^{(Z)}$ means zeta regularization) is very different to $\sum_{k\ge 1}^{(Z)} (-1)^{k+1} k = \lim_{s \to -1} \eta(s)$ where $\eta(s) =  \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k+1} k^{-s}$ for $s > 0$, and continued analytically to every $s $. Then $\mathcal{O}(1/\epsilon)$ is clearly not what you meant.

Comment: The analytic continuation regularization of divergent series is to evaluate $\sum_{k\ge 1}^{(A)} a_k$ by $\lim_{s \to 0} F(s)$ where $F,f_k$ are analytic on $U \ni 0$, $f_k(0) = a_k$, and $F(s) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty f_k(s)$ converges and is analytic for $|s-c| < r \subset U$. The result depends on $F,f_k, U$.

Comment: @reuns What if I restrict only to non-oscillatory divergences where the partial sums actually tend to infinity? Is the problem well-defined then?